# Mail::send vs Mail::queue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am struggling with a bit of a weird problem I have a laravel 5.2 application witch has e-mail functionality by using ::send in the Mail facade.I replaced all send calls with queue calls.

I migrated the queue table and changed .env setting

> QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

to

> QUEUE_DRIVER=database

I don't receive any error when running `php artisan queue:work --daemon` the job is sent to queue and processed after removed but ... no e-mail received. If I change back to sync it works fine.

What can be the cause of this problem? Diffed php.ini from cli to apache2 no difference that can affect this.

Here is my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=edited
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=edited
MAIL_PASSWORD=edited
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: I tried even hardcoding the smtp settings in config/mail.php

Comment: Have you checked the spam / junk folder for the email?

Comment: @NirajShah yes of course

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed following command after changing QUEUE_DRIVER=database in .env:

php artisan queue:table

may be it will help.

Comment: I migrated the queue table